# Allow only one active session per user in Amazon Cognito

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito as the authentication system for my nodejs application, and as a security requirement, I have to allow only one active session per user.

One way that I could think to do that is:

1. User try to log in, so call `globalSignOut(params = {}, callback)` and invalidate all other active sessions
2. After invalidate the other sessions, call `initiateAuth(params = {}, callback)`, and return user's authentication tokens.

My question is, there is another way to do that? Maybe a more "official" one?

I'm using aws-sdk for JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "official" way to do this. The method you stated in your question is the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 2):

The Above mentioned solution is not working well.
what I am doing to handle single device login

1. On Successful login. Get the access token and other token.
2. call globalLogout with the above tokens.
3. Again call Login initiateAuth and get new tokens and return them to server.

I am able to get the token after 3rd step. but when I try to use it says "Access Token has been revoked".

P.S. I am making sure that above 3 steps happen synchronously but still facing the problem.

Comment: Check https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/9838 regarding the "access token has been revoked" message, it may be a bug in the library. If that's the case you can try the workaround they propose there retrying sign in after the failure