# Cognito: How to check if user has already open session

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have to manage the following case:
the user logged in via a desktop browser.
After she/he tries to login in via another browser, I should remove the previous session and create the new session.

Is it possibile?
I am using amplify library to manage the login in/out in Cognito.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to use await Auth.signOut({ global: true }); but it works if i open two pages on the same browser.

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55457411/allow-only-one-active-session-per-user-in-amazon-cognito